# Chrome extension warns "Cannot load extension with file or directory name Thumbs.db. The filename is illegal."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Whenever I use "*load unpacked*" to test my custom Chrome extension, I get an error:

> There were warnings when trying to install this extension:
>
> - Cannot load extension with file or directory name Thumbs.db. The filename is illegal.

I am testing my extension by:

- Opening Chrome's extensions page (`chrome://extensions`)
- Ensuring "*Developer mode*" is enabled in the top-right corner
- Clicking "*Load unpacked*" and selecting my extension folder.

I don't see `Thumbs.db` in my extension folder, so I'm not sure what the warning is for.

Comment: As the error message says, there's a `thumbs.db` file inside. [Delete it](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+delete+thumbs.db). As well as this question :-)

Comment: I'm having this issue too. Deleting the thumbs.db doesn't fix the issue, the message keeps popping up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19):

Open Windows 'Folder Options' and select the 'View' tab. Under 'Advanced Settings', select 'Show hidden files, folders, and drives' then select 'OK'.

Doing this will show the `Thumbs.db` file inside the folder where you are keeping pictures/icons relevant to your extension. Delete it.

To prevent creation of `Thumbs.db` again, I reckon, setting the folder type to 'General Items' should do the trick.

[image: Folder "Customize" tab]

Comment: When I try to do this, I get an error deleting the file: right click on thumbs.db > Delete > confirm I want to delete a system file > ERROR: The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows Explorer

Answer (score 8):

To fix this enter the path:

> Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\File Explorer Options

Click

> View

In "advanced setting" Uncheck

> Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)

And apply

---

To Prevent this from occurring make sure in

> Properties (Customize)

of that folder that

> Optimize this folder for:

is

> "General Items"

Comment: I would like google chrome to ignore .db files and other system files.  It would remove hassle!

Answer (score 7):

As wOxxOm said, there is a thumbs.ds archive inside. If you are using Windows, a `ds` file can be understood as a protected operational system file. So everything you need to do is go to control panel -> folders options and unmark "hide protected operational system files" or something like this.

Answer (score -3):

I have already face this problem and finaly i have solve it,when you load your extension folder to chrome then go to detail option and off the collect errors. you will never seen the error this is just like notice error it does not effect your extension.
[You can see the image for help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Id1E.png)