# In my Chrome extension, what is Thumbs.db and can I delete it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Disclaimer: I'm pretty new to creating Chrome extensions; I'm just working off of one that was already created by the developer for me, so apologies if I am too vague or missing information!

I was giving a folder with the source code for a Chrome Extension, and when I upload it to my Extensions, it works perfectly fine with no errors that occur while using it. BUT, I see this error notice (screenshot attached)[screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2siPO.png)

Upon clicking the error, I see "Cannot load extension with file or directory name Thumbs.db. The filename is illegal."

I looked this up and sure enough, it doesn't seem specific to my code or anything. One person[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2siPO.png) seems to have resolved the issue with the advice given to delete Thumbs.db (resource attached with full solution).

Basically, the stack exchange question attached is my problem and has a solution, but I don't really understand it and want more context.

I also don't want to delete something I'm not sure about. Can somebody explain...

- What is this file?
- Why does deleting it fix the problem?
- Are there risks?

Thanks!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2siPO.png) - [Issue for the Chrome Extension File not getting uploaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32456001/issue-for-the-chrome-extension-file-not-getting-uploaded)

Answer (score 0):

> What is
>   [Thumbs.db](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/what-are-thumbsdb-files-and-can-i-delete-them-windows.htm):

"Thumbs.db is much like its name. It stores graphics, movie, and some document files then generates a preview of the folder contents using a thumbnail cache."

> Why does deleting it fix the problem?

"Probably Chrome Extension design policy"

> Are there risks?

"None that I know of"

Comment: I guess what I don't understand is, if it's storing things...how does deleting it not affect the application? What's the point of them if they can just be deleted? I still don't really understand